# What are canonical vectors?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I just begun with linear programming. Given an objective function $z$ and certain restrictions defined by $Ax = b$, we got to find the values necessary to maximise or minimise that function's output... using the method "simplex".

First I have a definition for "canonical linear program". One of its points says:

> The $m$ canonical vectors $e_1,e_2,...,e_m$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ are
>   columns in $A$, in some order. The variables associated with such
>   columns are called basic variables.

Nice, so the canonical vectors are columns in $A$... but what ***are*** canonical vectors...?

This is followed by an example:

> $$\begin{cases} -6x_1 + \color{red}{0} + \color{red}{x_3}-2x_4+2x_5=6
> > \\ -3x_1+\color{red}{x_2}+\color{red}{0}+6x_4+3x_5=15 \end{cases}$$
>
> The canonical vectors are the columns 2 and 3.

Okay. I only see two particular properties here: the columns only have one non-null term, and they also have a coefficient of 1. Is that what a canonical vector is?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it looks like by "canonical vector" they mean "standard basis vector," i.e. a vector whose components consist of one 1 and otherwise 0s. This is typically what the symbols $e_i$ represent (in linear algebra anyway).

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what "canonical vectors" are.